# Confluent Control Center not starting for cp-all-in-one docker file

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I am running **Confluent Platform all-in-one** docker-compose file on my Mac by the steps described in [this confluent doc](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html).
However, when every container is up (checked using `docker-compose ps`), I cannot reach the Control Center web interface at `http://localhost:9021/`. I waited a lot, so it could not be an issue with starting up.
I also checked the url with IP of the docker image plus port 9021 - still unable to connect.

Why could that be, and how can I fix that?

Comment: You need to increase your Docker memory settings to run that all in one compose file

Comment: Did you try to exec into the control center container and curl it there? Or check running processes to see if the server started? Otherwise, show `docker-compose logs` from the container

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same problem and was able to fix it by using .arm64 based images as I was having mac with Apple M1 Pro chipset. So, in the default docker-compose.yml image names I just appended .arm64 at the end and it started working for me.

I hope it helps for someone in future.